# Как изменять параметры размера двумерного массива в классе?

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

Я имею следущий массив:

```
const int M = 3, N = 3;
int fields[M][N];
```

Я знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью динамиечского массива, но у меня возникаают проблемы с правильностью записи.

Написал следущее:

```
        double** fields = new double* [R];
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            fields[i] = new double[V];
        }
```

Но в классах это не работает.

Comment: Что значит "не работает в классах"? Нормальный код, только и того, что выделяете R указателей, а инициализируете m... Исправить m на R и все в порядке...

Comment: Да, спасибо, инициализировал функцию, перенеся значения массива и получилось сделать адаптивные значения размеров массива.